# Work out which component an event is coming from

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component for a checkbox that is used in multiple components.

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
    return (
        <Col>
            <div className="switch">
                <input id={props.value} type="checkbox" value={props.value} className="visually-hidden" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
                <label htmlFor={props.value} className="switch-label checkbox-label text-center">{props.label}</label>
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}

export default Checkbox
```

I want to have a single function that handles the change from this component but work out the parent component that called it so I can update the correct value in my state.

For example, I have an Attendees component that uses my checkbox component:

```
export default class Attendees extends Component {
    state = {
        attendees: [
            {id: 1, value: 500, label: "0 - 500", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 1500, label: "500 - 1.5k", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 5000, label: "1.5k - 5k", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 10000, label: "5k - 10k", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 25000, label: "10k - 25k", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 50000, label: "25k - 50k", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: 1000000, label: "50k+", checked: false},
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h4 className="ui centered question-header text-center">HOW MANY ATTENDEES DO YOU EXPECT?</h4>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {
                        this.state.attendees.map((number) => {
                            return (<Checkbox name="attendees" key={number.value}
                                           handleChange={this.props.handleChange} {...number} />)
                        })
                    }
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When my handleChange function gets fired I want to know if it came from the attendees component so I can update my attendee's value in my state, currently I have this as my handleChange function which only updates the event_format on my state. Is this possible?

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            event_format: [],
            attendees: 0,
        }

        this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleCheckboxChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        let value = target.value;
        let eventFormatsCopy = this.state.event_format;
        if (target.checked) {
            eventFormatsCopy.push(value)
            this.setState({
                event_format: eventFormatsCopy
            })
        } else {
            const index = eventFormatsCopy.indexOf(value)
            eventFormatsCopy.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState({
                event_format: eventFormatsCopy
            })
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }
```

Comment: you are passing the same reference to `eventFormatsCopy`, you need to create a copy `let eventFormatsCopy = [...this.state.event_format];` otherwise you are mutating your state array

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but could you just check whether `target.name === 'attendees'`? (I'm also assuming <Radio ... /> is the checkbox component?)

Comment: If I console log event.target.name it seems to be blank

Comment: If you pass additional props to the input you'll get the name through and back: `<input type="checkbox" {...props} />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this has already been answered, but the accepted answer is A Bad Idea™ in my opinion, so I offer these simple alternatives.

### 1. Pass a different handler:

```
  <Checkbox onChange={this.handleAttendeesChange} />
  <Checkbox onChange={this.handleOtherStuff} />
```

Or if you really need to use a single handler for whatever reason, you can…

---

### 2. Use the input's name:

If you pass the `name` prop through to the input you can test `target.name` in your change handler:

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
    return (
        <Col>
            <div className="switch">
                <input
                    name={props.name} {/* pass the name prop to the input */}
                    id={props.value}
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={props.value}
                    className="visually-hidden"
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor={props.value} className="switch-label checkbox-label text-center">{props.label}</label>
            </div>
        </Col>
    )
}

export default Checkbox
```

```
// unchanged from your example
<Checkbox
    name="attendees"
    key={number.value}
    handleChange={this.props.handleChange}
    {...number}
/>
```

```js
handleCheckboxChange(event) {
   if (event.target.name === 'attendees') {
      // do attendee stuff
   }
   else {
      // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Number 1 doesnt satisfy the OPs requirement of _"I want to have a single function that handles the change from this component but work out the parent component that called it"_.

Comment: @james Fair enough. Strikes me as an odd requirement that smells like a design flaw, but I admit I didn’t spend a lot of time or attention on it.